# NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.password while updating data

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I got the error **NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.password** while updating the data from a Form. 
I am using a Custom User Model. Everything works fine but, while updating data from the admin form I got this error.

***modles.py***

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager,
    AbstractBaseUser
)



class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have a username.')
        else:
            username = username.lower()
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Password required!')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user_obj = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            #is_staff = is_staff,
            #is_active = is_active,
            #is_admin = is_admin,
            #date_of_birth = date_of_birth,
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save(using = self._db)
        return user_obj


    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin',True)
        return  self._create_user(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            **extra_fields
        )

    def create_user(self, username, email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin',False)
        return  self._create_user(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            **extra_fields
        )

    def create_webuser(self, username, email, password, firstname, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin',False)
        return self._create_user(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            password = password, 
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name
            **extra_fields
        )



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    GET_COLOR_CODE = (
        ('PI', 'PINK'),
        ('BL', 'BLUE'),
        ('RE', 'RED'),
        ('YL', 'YELLOW'),
        ('GR', 'GREEN')
    )
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = GET_COLOR_CODE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 33, unique = True)
    first_name = models.CharField("First name of the user", max_length = 33)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last name of the user", max_length = 33)
    email = models.EmailField("Email of user", max_length = 255, unique = True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    #date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default =True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)def inscription(request):

    object = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','first_name','last_name'] # to create python manage.py createsuperuser

    def get_username(self):
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name+' '+self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.is_active

    @property
    def admin(self):
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def staff(self):
        return self.is_staff
```

This is Traceback I found.

```
Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['accounts',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'phonenumber_field']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  303.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.password) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  575.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1557.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1451.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1491.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1027.         obj.save()

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in save
  73.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  759.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  823.                                       forced_update)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_update
  872.         return filtered._update(values) > 0

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _update
  709.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1379.         cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1068.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  303.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /locdev/accounts/user/11/change/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.password
```

I'm not understanding what the problem is. Please anyone can help me!

Comment: check what is the password you are getting through the form

Comment: Password is encrypted through SHA key. Is any other way to check stored password?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't migrate the model.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

then add this code in settings.py file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.User'
```

**myApp** is name of the app that you write User model on there.

Comment: I'm migrating(using both command) my module after each change.

Comment: I've already added this line **AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'** in my settings.py. Actually i'm thinking something is missing or wrong in my User model.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because while updating your data from admin panel, django sets the password field to null and it breaks the not null constraint of password field.

You can add this to your **UserChangeForm** where you have defined your form inherited from  Modelform.

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields=('username','email', 'firstname','lastname', 'is_active','is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial['password']
```

This sets the same initial password for the updated data.